# Segments sum algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sum, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the following task:

1) Given the array A of size N.
2) Given set of *range update* queries i.e. (L, R, val) that should do *A[i] += val* for L <= i <= R. 
3) Given the set of *range sum* queries i.e. (L, R) that should return *sum(A[i])* for  L <= i <= R.

Constraints:

1) Size of A, segments and queries sets   N, N1, N2 <= 2^24.
2) 0 <= L <= 2^24, 0 <= R <= 2^24, 0 <= val <= 2^24.

Problem is to calculate *sum of all range sum queries* (S) modulo 2^32.

It seems that one may implement **Segment tree** to get desired sum with *O(NlogN)* time but actually we ***don't*** need to use this data structure. Instead, we can somehow calculate S in *O(N)* time just using 2 or 3 arrays. What is the general idea here?

I has recently wrote some algorithm in C++ to this problem but that is not optimal. Pseudocode:

1. Create two arrays Add[0..N-1] and Substract[0..N-1].
2. Iterate over the set of range updates and do Add[L] += val and Substract[R] += val.
3. Create array Partial_sum[0..N]
4. Partial_sum[0] = 0, what_to_add = 0.
5. For i in [1..N]:
   5.1. Partial_sum[i] = Partial_sum[i - 1] + Add[i - 1] + what_do_add
   5.2.  what_do_add = what_to_add + Add[i - 1] - Substract[i - 1]

We get *Partial_sum* array and can easily calculate any segment sum (L, R) in *O(1)* time just like  *Partial_sum[R+1] - Partial_sum[L]*.

But, the problem is that step 2 is too slow. Also, the loop in step 5 is hard to undestand. That is O(n) solution but constant is too high. I know there should be the way to improve step 5 but I don't undestand how to do this.

Could someone give some ideas or even suggest their own algorithm to solve this problem?

Thank you.

My algorithm implementation:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef unsigned long long ULL;


//MOD and size of A
const ULL MOD  = 4294967296LL; // 2^32
const size_t N = 16777216;     // 2^24

//params for next_rand()
UINT seed = 0;
UINT a;
UINT b;


//get random segment
UINT next_rand()
{
    seed = seed * a + b;
    return seed >> 8;
}


int main()
{
    UINT N1, N2;

    std::cin >> N1 >> N2;
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    UINT* add  = new UINT[N];         //Add array
    UINT* subs = new UINT[N];         //Substraction array
    UINT* part_sum = new UINT[N + 1]; //Partial sums array

    memset(add, 0, sizeof(UINT) * N);
    memset(subs, 0, sizeof(UINT) * N);
    memset(part_sum, 0, sizeof(UINT) * (N + 1));  //Initialize arrays

    //step 2 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
    {
        UINT val = next_rand();
        UINT l   = next_rand();
        UINT r   = next_rand();

        if (l > r)
        {
            std::swap(l, r);
        }

        add[l]  = (add[l] + val);
        subs[r] = (subs[r] + val);
    }

    part_sum[0]   = 0;
    UINT curr_add = 0;

    //step 5
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        part_sum[i] = (part_sum[i - 1] + curr_add + add[i - 1]);

        curr_add = (curr_add + add[i - 1] - subs[i - 1]);
    }

    UINT res_sum = 0;

    //Get any segment sum in O(1)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N2; ++i)
    {
        UINT l = next_rand();
        UINT r = next_rand();

        if (l > r)
        {
            std::swap(l, r);
        }
        res_sum = (res_sum + part_sum[r + 1] - part_sum[l]);
    }

    std::cout << res_sum;

    delete []add;
    delete []subs;
    delete []part_sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code so far for improvements.

Comment: What if next_rand returns an out of bounds index? Why is random process required? Maybe I don't understand the problem.

Comment: You may just avoid next_rand() function because it always return values  from [0, 2^24 - 1].
The problem is in algorithm. It works too slow if N1 = 2^24, N2 = 2^24. There should be the way to use only 2 arrays instead of 3 and perform step 5 more clearly but I don't know how.

Comment: In next_rand() seed can'be more that 2^24 because it is unsigned int and so we have modulo 2^32 arithmetic. When we do (seed >> 8) we just get the values not more than 2^32/2^8 = 2^24

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented described algorithm in different way. It should work faster. It should work faster than before at maximum values of update and sum query sizes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef unsigned long long ULL;

const ULL MOD  = 4294967296LL; // 2^32
const size_t N = 16777216;     // 2^24

UINT seed = 0;
UINT a;
UINT b;

UINT next_rand()
{
    seed = seed * a + b;

    return seed >> 8;
}

std::vector <std::pair<UINT, UINT> > add;

int main()
{
    UINT upd_query_count;
    UINT sum_query_count;

    // freopen("fastadd.in",  "r", stdin);
    // freopen("fastadd.out", "w", stdout);

    scanf("%u", &upd_query_count);
    scanf("%u", &sum_query_count);
    scanf("%u", &a);
    scanf("%u", &b);

    add.reserve(N+1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < upd_query_count; ++i)
    {  
        UINT val = next_rand();
        UINT l   = next_rand();
        UINT r   = next_rand();

        if (l > r)
        {
            add[r].first     += val;
            add[l + 1].first -= val;
        }
        else
        {
            add[l].first     += val;
            add[r + 1].first -= val;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sum_query_count; ++i)
    {
        UINT l = next_rand();
        UINT r = next_rand();

        if (l > r)
        {
            ++add[r].second;
            --add[l + 1].second;
        }
        else
        {
            ++add[l].second;
            --add[r + 1].second;
        }
    }

    UINT curr_add = 0;
    UINT res_sum  = 0;
    UINT times    = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        curr_add += add[i].first;
        times    += add[i].second;

        res_sum += curr_add * times;
    }

    printf("%u\n", res_sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So `add` ad `subs` are *very* large arrays.

The first place you should look for a speed up here is in memory access. As `N1` becomes large you will end up with a tremendous number of cache misses. This is probably somewhat beyond the scope to explain so I'll link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache

As far as a way you can speed this up. Lets try to improve spatial equality by ordering our access.

```
std::vector<std::pair<UINT, UINT>> l{N1};
std::vector<std::pair<UINT, UINT>> r{N1};

for(size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i){
    const UINT val = next_rand();
    const UINT first = next_rand();
    const UINT second = next_rand();

    if(first > second){
        l[i] = std::make_pair(second, val);
        r[i] = std::make_pair(first, val);
    }else{
        l[i] = std::make_pair(first, val);
        r[i] = std::make_pair(second, val);
    }
}
std::sort(l.begin(), l.end());
std::sort(r.begin(), r.end());

for(size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i){
    add[l[i].first] += l[i].second;
    subs[r[i].first] += r[i].second;
}
```

Keep a couple things in mind, `std::pair`'s `operator<` compares the `first` element and if those are equal compares the `second`. That's how I'm able to use `std::sort` without writing any more code. However if `first` is equal for two elemnts, the highest `val` will always be the second one added. It doesn't seem like that would be a problem in your current code, but if it becomes one you can solve it by writing your own sort loop, rather than relying on `std::sort`.

Also depending on how sparse access is to each cache block it may be faster to do your additions in separate loops.

As always the only way you can really improve performance is when working with actual numbers so be sure to do your own bench marking as your're comparing methods.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Two moments:
1) That is O(NlogN) solution so it spends even more time than before<br>
2) This solution eats more memory than before<br>
3) I forgot to mention that we don't need to use more than 256 Mb

Is there some way to solve this problem using only 3 loops and without sort?

Actually, good solution should spend less than 256 Mb and works for N = N1 = N2 = 2^24 less than 4 seconds. Cheers

Comment: @PeterLeontev 1) Big-O notation is useful if all operations have the same cost here they do not 2) You can always add more memory to a person's computer, you can never add more time to their life 3) I presume there is importance to the order values are read from `next_rand` since you are always putting the smaller one go in `l`? If this is the case, I don't think that you can save space by splitting the initialization loop.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for the advices. I've realized how one can improve speed of this algorithm. We need just mark the segments bounds (update queries) in some array and then count how many times bound from the sum queries occurs. This solution also requires 3 loops.

Comment: @PeterLeontev Great! If you could post your solution as an answer here it would probably be helpful for any future viewers of this question.